# Can't apply update to Windows 10 - error 0xC1900200

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1511

I've been running Wndows 10 for a while. When it tries to update to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586, I get the following in the event log:

```
Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0xC1900200: Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, version 1511, 10586.
```

My research shows this error says something is incompatible so I can't upgrade, however I'm already running Windows 10.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you make any hardware or bios changes after the original install of w10?

Comment: No hardware or bios changes other than a USB device (Hauppauge 955Q)

Comment: share the folder **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther** on onedrive, so that  can see what fails .

Comment: Shared : https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=ADF9418B94B1226A&resid=ADF9418B94B1226A%215420&authkey=AO_t-Aq06Jre6Ho

Comment: I can't see the setuperr.log in it, that I need

Comment: Ok, out there now.

Comment: windows can't find the file NewSystem.dat: **Cannot resurrect new system.: Win32Exception: \\?\C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\NewSystem.dat: The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Looked around and didn't see any solid fixes. Any ideas?

Comment: I've asked Microsoft for help and will reply if I get an answer.

Comment: Microsoft needs again all data. make sure really ALL logs/data from **C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther** are included in your zip

Comment: Thanks! I zipped all files and u/led them here so I'm sure they're all there: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=ADF9418B94B1226A!5515&authkey=!AAzwbHTxxfml0Nw&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: oik, I send the link to MS. If I get an answer, I'll reply here again.

Comment: Heard anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this was tied to this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086249#bookmark-w8mbr). Turns out there was not enough space on the reserved partition. So, I expanded the partition with [this tool](http://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html) to 350mb, restarted and applied the update. It worked after that.

Comment: That didn't work for me. My System Reserved partition was nearly full (100MB left from 500MB), so I formatted it, now it's empty and I get the error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> You may encounter the problem in your  Windows 10 update Error code 0xC1900200 – 0x20008 – 0xC1900202 – 0x20008. Please follow the below troubleshooting steps to fix the  Windows 10 update Error code 0xC1900200 – 0x20008 – 0xC1900202 – 0x20008 problem.
>
> Manually reset the Windows update.
>
> 1. Click “Start”, type “cmd”in the Start search box.
> 2. Right-click “cmd” and select “Run as administrator”.
> 3. On the open Command Prompt window copy and paste the commands (all at once) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
    net stop wuauserv  
    net stop cryptSvc    
    net stop bits    
    net stop msiserver    
    ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old    
    ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old    
    net start wuauserv    
    net start cryptSvc    
    net start bits    
    net start msiserver    
    pause
```

> Now reboot the computer and check if Windows 10 update Error Code 0xC1900200 – 0x20008 – 0xC1900202 – 0x20008 is fixed now. If not, please continue the troubleshooting to fix Windows 10 update Error Code 0xC1900200 – 0x20008 – 0xC1900202 – 0x20008

Please refer to [this link](http://www.msofficelivesupport.com/windows-update/windows-10-update-error-code-0xc1900200-0x20008-0xc1900202-0x20008/) for more information.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.